# Open link in new window with Jquery

Tags: jquery, load

I am trying to open a few links in a new window using Jquery rather than _blank so my html remains valid. My code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[id="external-url"]').click(function(){
        $(this).attr('target','_blank');
    });
});
```

This works just fine except when the link is contained within html I have placed on the page using the Jquery load() method. Can anyone explain why and please help with a solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update:** If you're reading this in an HTML5+ world [the `target` attribute is no longer deprecated](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html#a.attrs.target) ([no longer missing, to be more accurate](http://learningtheworld.eu/2007/xhtml-with-target/)) as [it was in XHTML 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#dtdentry_xhtml1-strict.dtd_a) (the original question context).  I suggest if you're reading this now, *ignore everything below*, **use the `target` attribute whether it throws a compliance warning or not**, all browsers support it and it never should have been left out...the fact it was added back in a later spec shows removing it was a mistake.

---

This will work:

```
$('a#external-url').live('click', function(){
  $(this).attr('target','_blank');
});
```

However, IDs should be unique, if you're loading more than 1, they need to have a class instead, like this:

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="exteral-url">Google</a>
```

And jQuery like this:

```
$('a.external-url').live('click', function(){
  $(this).attr('target','_blank');
});
```

The standards compliant way would be:

```
$('a.external-url').live('click', function(e){
  window.open(this.href);
  e.preventDefault(); //or return false;
});
```

Comment: -1 _blank has been deprecated! Even though you are working around the validation by adding the attribute using script.

Comment: @James - I was fixing the issue of the click not binding by the OP.  If they want to bypass validation, that's their call, not mine to make, the question is about the javascript not working.  As a side note, *normally* I'd agree, but `_blank` being deprecated at all was a mildly retarded mistake on W3C's part.  I will bet you $100 that 5 years from now **every** browsers will still support `_blank`.

Comment: I got to admit I was midly surprised when I found out about this myself, but we cant choose which standards to ignore now can we ... tried to chaneg the vote down but its too old *sigh*

Comment: @James - Edited, added the standards compliant way, it is a perfectly valid point :)

Comment: This answer is wrong unless you use something like XHTML 1.1/2, see my answer below.

Comment: @rFactor - I added an update with more info, I agree anyone finding this today is better off ignoring this answer and using the `target` attribute regardless of warnings.  At the time of the original answer, it wasn't sure it was going to be added back to the XHTML specification...or what the future of HTML5 was.  Now that we know both, we can safely say complying with the XHTML 1.0 strict spec is a totally unnecessary complication.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(function(){
    $('a[id="external-url"]').click(function(){
        window.open(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

http://snipplr.com/view/4626/jquery-snip--open-link-in-new-window/

Answer (score 1):

Use **[.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)**

```
$('a[id="external-url"]').live("click", function(){
        $(this).attr('target','_blank');
    });
```

Your code will bind click event to elements that are available at the page load and not to dynamically created elements. Live will bind events to elements that are dynamically created also.

Answer (score 1):

On the contrary what others believe, the `target` attribute with all its values are *not* deprecated as per HTML5 specification.

You can read it about here: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html

> The target attribute on the a element was deprecated in a previous
>   version of HTML, but is no longer deprecated, as it useful in Web
>   applications, particularly in combination with the iframe element.

So, feel free to use it in HTML5.

Comment: Awesome! Looks like W3C realized their mistake :P

Comment: This isn't entirely accurate (with regards to the original context of this question). It *was* deprecated (missing, but you'll hear it as deprecated) in XHTML, it's re-added in XHTML later (which I completely agree with, it never should have been deprecated in the first place).

Comment: Yes it was deprecated, but as of now, in HTML5, it is allowed.