# jquery click function and "new page"

Tags: jquery

i use jQuery "click" function. If use simple click on img is everything ok, but when on this image is link with tag 'target="_blank"' or user click right button, then 'open in new window', this function don't work.

How made that click function work, when user open link in new window?

My code:

```
$('.button_img').live('click', function(){
    alert('new');
    //do something
});

<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
<img class="button_img" src="img.png" />
</a>
```

Comment: You don't. The user is in control of their browser as they should be.

Answer (score 0):

this should work I think

```
$('.button_img').live('click', function(){
   $(this).attr('target','_blank');
    //do something
});
```

or you can try this

```
$('.button_img').live('click', function(){
   window.open(this.href);
   e.preventDefault(); //or return false;
});
```

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606282/open-link-in-new-window-with-jquery) for more information

Comment: You're adding `target=_blank` to an img.

Comment: I think you completely missed the point of the question, because this isn't at all relevant.

Comment: Jayanga>thanks, but you wrong understand my problems. I don't need open link in new page. My click function does not work, when user open link in new windows. That is problem.

Comment: sorry my bad I will try again to provide an answer

Answer (score 0):

You cant prevent the user from opening a new tab, the only thing I can think of is not using a `<a></a>` tag, so they won't even get the option, but it'll still look like a clickeable element like this:

JS

```
$('.button_img').live('click', function(){
    alert('new');
    //do something

    //If you want to redirect to, for example, google in some case you do:
    //window.location = "http://www.google.com";
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="fakeLink">
     <img class="button_img" src="img.png" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .fakeLink {
        cursor:pointer;
        /*     styles     */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add "return false;" in the end of your click function:

```
$('.button_img').live('click', function(){
    alert('new');
    //do something
   return false;
});
```

This will prevent opening new window after left mouse button click.
And please, don't do anything whith right mouse button cklick - this is user business do it, or not.

Comment: Thanks for "return false;" ;). But i need count all clicks, so i need and catch "page in new window"